# Solr and multivalue fields

Tags: solr, content-search

I have a field in Sitecore that contains data such as "2010,2011,2012,2013" or "Europe;Asia;Africa;Artic" etc. These are string fields and don't need to be anymore than strings. These fields come from an external system. I would like to use them as filters on a listing page that I am creating. I would like to store them as computed fields in a Solr index. After I display them on the page they should look like this in a drop down -

```
--Select--
2010
2011
2012
2013
```

My computed field looks something like this in the index configuration file -

```
<field fieldName="year" storageType="yes" returnType="stringCollection" indexType="untokenized">Class, Library</field>
```

I have some code which basically uses splits up the string into a List of a string to pass the value in to the computed field.

When I read it from the Solr index, I do not always get all the values back and it only gives me back a few values. After a rebuild the values change again and I may only get 3 out of 4 values; another time I may only get 1 or 2 after an index rebuild.

The code I'm using to read the field looks something like -

```
items.Select(x => x.Document.Year).Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

Am I doing  this correct? Should I be using some other returnType or object type in my configuration?

Comment: If the values "2010,2011,2012,2013" in a field already, why do you need to use SOLR? Can you just use that field as a datasource for the drop down field? Or is this drop down an html select input?

Comment: @Gabbar maybe this can help you https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-and-solr-custom-field-reader-and-indexing

Comment: @dnstommy .. I have thousands of records and they all have different sets of '2011, 2013' or '2009, 2011,2012' etc. I just want them to be stored in the index so that I can read them directly from the index.

Comment: Do you want just the set that is in the field of the current item or all the possible sets in the index for all items?

Comment: @MarekMusielak .. I think you jut answered my question. I will give it a shot.

Comment: @dnstommy .. I have two scenarios. On the initial page load, when potentially all data loads, I want all the unique values in the drop down. When the search result set is filtered by other filters, I want this drop down to only show available values.

Comment: @Gabbar was the link helpful?

Comment: Will give it a try later this week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it sounds like you would like to do a facet
facets = context.GetQueryable()
                  .FacetOn(x => x.Year)
                  .GetFacets();

the facets is a collection of collections with facet categories (the field YEAR) and inside a collection of facet values (2001, 2002 etc).
this is distinct by nature and does not require you to get ANY documents from the index